# PHP script: Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, mysql-error-1064

I use the following code to connect to the database on my webserver:

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "database_name");
```

This connection works fine, I can use my website (which makes a lot of queries to the database) without a problem.

However I am facing a problem with a PHP script that loads about 8000 products from a product feed. At each product that I load I make a connection with the database (and I close this connection when a product is done loading).
When I start this script up it usually (it somehow sometimes works) gives the following error (note: this error occurs directly at the start, it doesn't load any products):

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in
```

I am aware that there are already many other topics with this same error, however I have not managed to resolve my issue. One of the things I have attempted is to replace 'localhost' with '127.0.0.1'. However this changes the error mentioned above to:

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in
```

I hope someone has an idea why these errors occur I look forward for your input, thank you.

Comment: read this for persistent connections: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.persistconns.php

Comment: try writing `p:localhost` to the hostname and share what happens with us.

Comment: Just to be sure: could you change your script so it only uses one database connection? I mean, open it at the start and don't close it until you've processed all the products...

Comment: Adding p:localhost didn't seem to work for me. The one database connection as suggested by Oscar does seem to have effect. I have opened my PHP script now 5 times (to speed up the loading of products, which is necessary because it takes a while to load a product into the database) however I now face the issue that I receive the 'Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory' on my website and also in my database when I try to open a table. I guess the reason behind this is that I can only have a limited number of open connections to the database?

Comment: It seems so. Look at http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.configuration.php

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar issue and the error is quite misleading. Though it doesn't directly answer the question above, I leave my findings below for those who landed on this page:

```
 1. mysql is not started and/or is not running (no such file error)
```

Check under `config/database.php` (permission denied)

```
2. username/password combination is wrong 
3. hostname: switch between `localhost` OR `127.0.0.1` (depends on how the password for the mysql user is set)
```

SELinux permission:

```
4. Check audit.log `tail -f /var/log/audit.log` when reloading the page 
   and see if any error similar to below occures:
```

`avc:  denied  { name_connect } for  pid=2440 comm="/usr/sbin/httpd" dest=3306 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:mysqld_port_t:s0 tclass=tcp_socket permissive=0`

If the above error occures, then execute as root `setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1`

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the exact same problem. just change the server name
from

```
localhost
```

to

```
localhost:3306
```